# Django how make a filter of foreignkey based on parent foreignkey selected in other form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a form for edit table Person, but in this form field Car must be filtered by selected Company. I'm very new to python/django so this may be a bad approach, high level suggestions welcome. Here is what I have:

I have 3 models in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

class Car(models.Model):
    car = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.car

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    people = Person.objects.all().select_related('car__company')
    table = PersonTable(people)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'table': table})

def edit(request, id):
    person = Person.objects.get(id = id)
    car = Car.objects.get(id = person.car_id)
    company = Company.objects.get(id = car.company_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(car.company_id, request.POST, instance=person)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/person/')
    else:
        companys = CompanyForm(instance=company)
        form = PersonForm(car.company_id, instance=person)
    return render(request, 'person/edit.html', {'companys':companys, 'form':form})

def Company_select(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanySelectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            return redirect('/person/edit/1/') # Return to form PersonForm with id=1. 
                                               # How to return selected Company?
                                               # How to return to page with other id?
    else:
        form = CompanySelectForm()
    return render(request, 'person/company_select.html', {'form':form})
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'person'
urlpatterns = [
    path('edit/<int:id>/', views.edit),
    path('company/', views.Company_select, name='company'),
    path('', views.index),
]
```

forms.py

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company',)

class CompanySelectForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all().order_by('company'))
    class Meta:
        fields = ('company',)

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'car',)
    def __init__(self, company, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['car'].queryset = Car.objects.filter(company=company)  #Filter by Company
```

edit.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}Edit{% endblock header %}
{% block content%}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    {{ companys.as_table }}
    <a href="/person/company/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Select Company</button></a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

company_select.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}Select Company{% endblock header %}
{% block content%}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the car company when the user select car for a person profile?

Comment: Houda, user should be able to change the company when changing an entry in the Person table and then the Car model filter will dynamically change according to the selected Company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install django-smart-selects

In models.py:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
...
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    car = ChainedForeignKey(
        Car,
        chained_field="company",
        chained_model_field="company",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposition : tested

form.py => add attribut that will call a JS function defined in your .html

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'company', 'car')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs,):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class SelectForm(Form):

    name = CharField(label='name')
    company = ChoiceField(label='company')
    car = ChoiceField(label='car')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'company', 'car', )

    def __init__(self, cars=None, *args, **kwargs, ):
        super(SelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['car'].choices = cars
        self.fields['company'].choices = tuple(Company.objects.all().values_list(flat=False))
        self.fields['company'].widget.attrs['onchange'] = "load_car()"
```

edit.html: => define the JS function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='myform' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
     </form>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</body>

<script>
function load_car()
{
    document.getElementById('myform').action = "/stack/myview";
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>


</html>
```

Views.py:=> new view that will look for the company name in the database and return to the template

```
  def index(request):  # RF configuration FORM
    form = PersonForm()
    content = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'stack/index.html', content)


def edit(request, my_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Do ....
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stack:index'))
        else:
            person = Person.objects.values_list().get(id__exact=my_id)
            cars = []
            [cars.append((x['car'], x['car'])) for x in
             list(Car.objects.filter(company__exact=person[2]).values('car'))]
            form = SelectForm(cars=cars, initial={'name': person[1], 'company': person[2], 'car': person[3]})
            content = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'stack/edit.html', content)
    else:
        person = Person.objects.values_list().get(id__exact=my_id)
        cars = []
        [cars.append((x['car'], x['car'])) for x in list(Car.objects.filter(company__exact=person[2]).values('car'))]
        form = SelectForm(cars=cars, initial={'name': person[1], 'company': person[2], 'car': person[3]})
        content = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'stack/edit.html', content)


def myview(request):
    cars = []
    [cars.append((x['car'], x['car'])) for x in list(Car.objects.filter(company__exact=request.POST['company']).
                                                     values('car'))]
    form = SelectForm(cars=cars, initial={'name': request.POST['name'], 'company': request.POST['company'], 'car': None})
    content = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'stack/edit.html', content)
```